# How to run C application Spike (RISC-V 32 simulator) without pk

Tags: simulator, riscv

I am porting an RTOS to RISC-V and I'd like to debug it. Trying to load the RTOS on low memory locations such as 0x0 or 0x1000 yields invalid load from debug module: 8 bytes at 0x0000000000001090. Loading it at 2GB (0x80000000), the spike does not give errors, however when I launch GDB it is unable to single step and viewing the program counter value shows a completely wrong program address 0x5c330dca.